# MaxLength property for textbox in code behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to use MaxLength function for the textbox in code behind.

How is it possible for textbox txttabname here, which is created dynamically. Any idea? Thanks a lot in advance!!

```
for (int i = 0; i < additionalPageCount; i++)
    {
        if (i == 0)
        {
            this.pnlProfilePages.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<tr><td colspan=\"4\" style=\"width:100px;font-size:11px; padding-bottom: 10px;\"><h3>Page Tabs</h3></td></tr>"));
        }
        this.pnlProfilePages.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<tr><td style=\"font-size:11px; padding-left:6px;\">Tab Name :</td><td style=\"padding-right:10px;font-size:11px;MaxLength:20\">"));
        string txtTabControlID = "txtTabName" + i.ToString();
        TextBox txtTab = new TextBox();
        txtTab.ID = txtTabControlID;
        txtTab.Width = 100;
        txtTab.TabIndex = lastTabIndex++;
    }
}
```

Comment: I notice that you're not actually adding the textbox...you're initializing it but you don't do anything with it. What are you hoping to be able to do after setting the MaxLength property?

Comment: Ohhh, My stupidity. I was mistaken. I am sorry. I know this property but somehow asked this?? :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
txtTab.MaxLength = 100;
```

Comment: Thanks Chris and sorry for asking this without thinking for the second time.

Answer (score 0):

```
txtTab.MaxLength = 20;
```

Is that what you're trying to do?